# How ASP MVC return json with variable name

Tags: c#, json

I have this user class

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

var users = new List<User>(){
    new User(){
        name = "Chriss",
        phone = "45096820",
        address = "xxx, street."
    },
    ...
};
```

How do i return using ASP MVC Json method

```
return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

that the return json format looks like the below

```
"Users"  :
    {
    "Chris" :
        {
            "phone" : "45096820",
            "address" : "xxx, street."
        },
    "Jason" :
        {
            "phone" : "406980968",
            "address" : "xxx, street"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you have 2 users with the same name?

Comment: Note that what you've show is not valid JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get exactly the same Json structure as you wanted, you will have to modify your User class to look like:

```
public class User
{
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

(without the name, the name will be the Key in your dictionary)

and use a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, User> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Controllers.User>();
        dictionary.Add("Chris", new User() { phone = "45096820", address = "xxx, street" });
        dictionary.Add("Jason", new User() { phone = "406980968", address = "xxx, street" });
        return Json(new { Users = dictionary }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the "trick" to naming the outermost JSON variable (the root property, so to speak) is to create an anonymous object with exactly that property:

```
return Json(new { Users = users }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Will return an object with one **array** property (`Users`).

If you need a JSON object with one **object** property (`Users`) which itself has two properties (`Chris` and `Jason`), consider using a `Dictionary<string, User>` (the key being a user's name) instead of a `List<User>`:

```
var users = new Dictionary<string, User>
{
    { "Chris", new User { phone = "45096820", address = "xxx, street." } },
    { "Jason", new User { phone = "406980968", address = "xxx, street." } }
};
```

Json.NET will serialize dictionaries like your desired output JSON format.

Comment: notice the name? the name title is not in the result.

Comment: @JeeShenLee Now you were faster typing your comment than me updating my answer. ;)